# Goto prior to a variable definition - what happens with its value?

Tags: c++, goto, local-variables, register-allocation

Here is some question I wondered about. Given the following code, can we be certain about its output?

```
void f() {
  int i = 0; 
  z: if(i == 1) goto x; else goto u; 
  int a; 
  x: if(a == 10) goto y; 
  u: a = 10; i = 1; goto z; 
  y: std::cout << "finished: " << a; 
}
```

Is this guaranteed to output `finished: 10` according to the C++ Standard? Or can the compiler occupy the register that `a` is stored into, when `goto` to a place prior to `a`?

Comment: Are you essentially asking whether a goto statement is a sequence point?

Comment: @Armen if `a` would be of class type, then jumping before it would call its destructor. So I was wondering about if it is of non-class type, would jumping before it invalidate its value? So jumping to `z`, and then to `u`, will `a` remain the value `10`, or some random other value possibly used by a local variable or some assembler operation at point `z`?

Comment: The C++0x standard is larger but better-written. In the meantime we're getting tangled-up in the legality rather than deal with the actuality. I'm increasingly convinced that the above code is undefined and should (even if legal) be rejected by the compiler.

Comment: @Xaade It's useful sometimes. Try writing a parser without using exceptions and you'll probably find plenty of untidy but necessary jump points.

Comment: @spraff Decision constructs replace goto. It may be possible in some cases to have gotos look more readable, but they are never necessary.

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** Read the comments to this one first. Johannes more or less shot down my whole argument with one well-placed standard quote. ;-)

---

I do not have the C++ standard available, so I have to extrapolate from the C standard.

Surprisingly enough (for me), chapter 6.2.1 *Scopes of identifiers* says nothing about the scope of an identifier starting at the point of its declaration (as I would have guessed). `int a`, in your example, has *block scope*, which "terminates at the end of the associated block", and that is all that is said about it. chapter 6.8.6.1 *The goto statement* says that "a goto statement shall not jump from outside the scope of an identifier having a variably modified type to inside the scope of that identifier" - but since your `goto`s jump around only *within* the block (and, thus, the scope of `int a`, that *seems* to be OK as far as ISO/IEC 9899:1999 is concerned.

I'm *quite* surprised about this...

**Edit #1:** A quick google later I got my hands on the C++0x final draft. The relevant statement, I think, is this here (6.7 *Declaration statement*, highlighting mine):

> It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that
>   bypasses declarations **with initialization**.
>   A program that jumps from a point where a variable with automatic
>   storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is
>   ill-formed **unless the variable has scalar type**, class type with
>   a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified
>   version of one of these types, or an array of one of the
>   preceding types **and is declared without an initializer**.

I think your code is OK by the standard's standards. But butt-ugly, mind you. ;-)

**Edit #2:** Reading your comment about the possible destruction of `int a` due to the jump backwards, I found this (6.6 *Jump statements*, highlighting mine):

> Transfer out of a loop, out of a block, or back past an **initialized variable**
>   with automatic storage duration involves the destruction of **objects** with
>   automatic storage duration that are in scope at the point transferred from but
>   not at the point transferred to.

One, `int a` is not "initialized", and it is not an object if I understand the standard terminology correctly.

Comment: `int` is not a variably modified type though. Wrt the *scope of a*, the C draft says "Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. Any other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator.". So I *am* jumping from outside of the scope of `a` to inside of it, though.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: That effectively voids my argument, which based on the somewhat vague definition of the term "block scope" I've been able to find at short notice. I could've pictured that, as far as `goto`'s are concerned, not actually passing through the declaration doesn't matter that much. The passage you quoted deflates that nicely. I'll let my answer stand as a bad example for language standard lawyerism. ;-)

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: The funny thing about C is: It does not allow variable definition after statements, right -- or does it in C99?

Comment: I only shut down your C spec quote tho. :)

Answer (score 6):

6.7/3 says that

> A program that jumps from a point where a local variable with
>   automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in
>   scope is illformed unless the variable has POD type (3.9) and is
>   declared without an initializer (8.5).

So that should be ok.

Then in 6.6/2:

> On exit from a scope (however accomplished), destructors (12.4) are
>   called for all constructed objects with automatic storage duration
>   (3.7.2) (named objects or temporaries) that are declared in that
>   scope, in the reverse order of their declaration.

Now this implies to me that `a` is toast when you jump back to `z` and you cant' make any guarantees about how the no-initializer declaration of `a` will behave the second time it executes.

See 6.7/2:

> Variables with automatic storage duration (3.7.2) are initialized each
>   time their declarationstatement is executed. Variables with automatic
>   storage duration declared in the block are destroyed on exit from the
>   block (6.6).

So it looks to me like there isn't a guarantee that you'll get 10 although it seems hard to imagine a compiler where that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: "it seems hard to imagine a compiler where that wouldn't be the case." - If it's legal, I can imagine it. The comparison `i == 1` might work by copying `i` into a register, copying `1` into a register, and comparing them. Meanwhile, the optimizer might have decided that `a` should be stored in a register. Finally, the same register might be allocated to `a` and to `1`, since `a` is not in scope when the comparison is performed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed to forgo a variable definition. It should be an error.

Comment: It *does* compile, and it *does* print `finished: 10`, at least with G++. Even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. The question is what the standard has to say about it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it guaranteed to output `finished: 10` according to the C++ Standard?

I think yes ,it must!

Why ? Because `a` lives from its declaration till the end of its scope (end of the function) and by definition it can only be initialized once and from there on retain its value until destruction which is at the end of the function.

Comment: In fact the standard says that if you go back before the declaration of a variable it gets destructed and can be initialized again.

Answer (score 0):

Why not determine this with assembly?

**Conclusion: The local variable will only be declared once; however, the assignments will all be performed each time.**

Justification below.

---

I simplified the problem:

main.cpp:

```cpp
int f() {
  //asm(";start f()");

  //asm(";begin: ");
  begin:
  int i = 0;
  if (i == 0)
  {
    i++;
    goto begin;
  }

  //asm(";after goto");
  return i + 2;
}

int main()
{
  //asm(";before f()");
  int i = f();
  //asm(";after f()");
  return i;
}
```

Then I compiled this into assembly (with the `asm`'s uncommented) on Linux with:

`g++ -std=c++20 -I/usr/include/c++/11 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11 -S main.cpp`

which output main.s (the assembly output of main.cpp). Here is the relevant part; I added in a bunch of dashes to make it more obvious:

```
#APP
# 2 "main.cpp" 1
-----------------------------------;start f()
# 0 "" 2
# 4 "main.cpp" 1
-----------------------------------;begin:
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
.L2:
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jne .L3
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
#APP
# 13 "main.cpp" 1
-----------------------------------;after goto
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $2, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   _Z1fv, .-_Z1fv
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
#APP
# 19 "main.cpp" 1
-----------------------------------;before f()
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    call    _Z1fv
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
#APP
# 21 "main.cpp" 1
-----------------------------------;after f()
```

Then, I compiled main.cpp using:

`g++ -std=c++20 -I/usr/include/c++/11 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11 main.cpp -omain`

It compiled fine. Then I ran it with:

`./main`

**And it was stuck in an infinite loop.**